# OpenWrt wifi bridge with IPv6

Tags: bridge, openwrt, ipv6

I am running OpenWrt 15.05 on my WDR4300.
My ISP is via cable with legacy-IPv4-only.

For IPv6 connectivity I use HE.net tunnel to receive a static IPv6 /64 subnet.
 
My office is in a different room and is only connected via WiFi.

I am using small routers in a reverse AP-Setup with OpenWrt  as a WiFi-Bridge. (WR703n, WT3020)
They run with the package relayd and convert the wifi signal back to ethernet for my devices on the switch.

For IPv4 it works fine. The WiFi client connects to the Wifi from the WDR4300.
All clients behind the WiFi-bridge have access to the dhcp server, gateway and cable WAN uplink. 
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/relayclient

The Wifi-WAN from the bridge is able to receive a IPv6 address. 
Still I couldn't figure out how to create a IPv6 wifi bridge to share IPv6 connectivity to my devices behind.